# Do stl vectors inside stl vectors go out of scope when the vector is cleared?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

In this code:

```
class myClass
{
    ...
    vector<myThing> thing(10);
    vector<myStuff> stuff(10);
    ...
}

vector<myClass> vecClass(10);
...
vecClass.clear();  /// calls destructor on myClass instances
```

Each element of `vecClass` holds 10 element vectors of thing and stuff. When `clear()` is called, does that make thing and stuff go out of scope, and thus be destroyed properly? Or is there something explicit that I have to do?

Comment: That's the beauty of RAII. If you don't say `new`, you don't say `delete`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, their destructors will be called. There is nothing else you need to do here.

Comment: But if myThing/myStuff have pointers it won't do a deep delete, Right?

Comment: Right, but then you should have written the destructors of `myThing` and `myStuff` to delete them. `vector` just calls the destructors of the things inside it.

Comment: Does that mean that for a stl object going out of scope,  clear or erase method is not called implicitly?

Comment: The destructor is called, not any other method.